# In unity3d client “push” an object with a rigidbody2d slower than the host

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, network-programming, client-server, game-physics

The game has an object that contains the component rigidbody2d and polygon collider. By design, the player can push it. When testing, network host pushes the object with a speed greater than the player-client. The sync position of the object is correct and the object correctly displays on host and client.

I'm trying to make the push force the same for both players.

Settings rigidbody2d and networkTransform on object and players are identical except for the weight and friction forces, and thus all the players can push each other with equal speed. In other words, the host pushes the client with the desired speed and the client host pushes with equal force.

Please help to resolve the issue. Attached screenshots of settings of the components

[screenshot of unity components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxT9u.png)

Comment: May be try change "Transform Sync Mode" to Sync Transform?

Comment: i tried. push power of players became the same, but the object started to lag. I couldn't resolve it. maybe it needs another settings?


however, if i resolve problem with another type of sync, it dont resolve core of problem - how to sync rigidbodies???